# How to fix border gap with border-radius?

Tags: css

I am having an issue with a circular border leaving a minor gap between the `<img>` and the border. This error happens with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox that I've tested. It does not happen when `border-radius` is 0.

In the second image you can see a small gap between the image and the border. How can I fix this?

[image]

The relevant css is:

```
border-radius:100px;
border:6px solid #202020;
```

The css is on the img tag as a style attribute. The answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28443685/overflow-hidden-with-border-radius-shows-a-weird-grey-border-over-images) question did not work.

Here is a fiddle reproducing the problem https://jsfiddle.net/8r8zcjvh/2/

Comment: I am unable to find the issue in the fiddle - Using Windows 10 Chrome latest. [**This is what I see**](https://i.imgur.com/HAO150W.png)... [**A better version of the image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6v5k.png)...

Comment: @PraveenKumar there is clearly a tiny red colored gap between the image and a border

Comment: @MateuszJuruś In my preview?

Comment: yes, in the photo you posted

Comment: you repeat the same question got closed 30min ago ... edit the other question or call the one how close it to reopen if you are not ok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a background with the same color:

```html
<div style="background:red">
<img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/949374088249671680/MuxDEZpD_400x400.jpg" style="border-radius:400px;border:4px solid darkblue; background: darkblue;">
</div>
```

Comment: This worked thank you.